# update the result in the table based on pass or fail in Oracle sql

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a table called `student_marks` , I have 5 subjects for all the students .I have inserted the marks as well , also i have updated the total of the marks . But in the result column i need to update pass or fail .How can i update this .

example

[image]

result should come as pass or fail

if any subject goes below 35 < fail else pass .

I dont know how to update this in the table. Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple update with case statement should work

```
UPDATE student_marks
SET result = 
  CASE WHEN 
    tamil < 35
    OR english < 35
    OR maths < 35
    OR science < 35
    OR social_science < 35
  THEN 'fail' ELSE 'pass' END;
```

Comment: A variant that may be somewhat more pleasing to the eye would be to use `LEAST(tamil, English, maths, science, social_science) < 35`. However, Kamil's solution is probably more efficient, since you don't really care to compute the "LEAST" - and the "CASE" statement moves on as soon as it encounters the first score below 35. If you need to squeeze the last milligram of efficiency, you may even put the hardest subject first (the one where it's most likely to see scores under 35) so "CASE" finishes early as many times as possible.